# Call to Undefined Method ::init Error

Tags: plugin-development

I'm getting this error when trying to call my plugin on a template:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Craft\SiteUtilitiesService::init() in /path/to/my/site/craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php on line 394

The template tag:

`{{ craft.siteUtilities.videoEmbed( block.video, '219181' ) }}`

Content of `variables/SiteUtilitiesVariable.php`:

```
class SiteUtilitiesVariable
{
    public function videoEmbed($url, $color)
    {
        return craft()->siteUtilities->videoEmbed($url, $color);
    }
}
```

Content of `services/SiteUtilitiesService.php`:

```
class SiteUtilitiesService
{
    public function videoEmbed($url, $color)
    {
        // some code to get the video ID from the $url variable

        return "<some html embed code with the $color variable>";
    }
}
```

What's the `init` method the error is referencing?

Comment: Stab in the dark, but if your main plugin class file extending BasePlugin?

Comment: @BradBell I actually wasn't extending `BaseApplicationComponent` in the Services file.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I meant to say. :)  Would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to extend `BaseApplicationComponent` in my Services file:

```
class SiteUtilitiesService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
    public function videoEmbed($url, $color)
    {
        // some code to get the video ID from the $url variable

        return "<some html embed code with the $color variable>";
    }
}
```